# Git: Creating a snapshot of my app current state

Tags: git, save, release, snapshot

I'm working on an app and I launch new releases quite often, and I'd like to keep "snapshots" of every new release as soon as it's ready for production just in case I need to go back and make bugfixes on that particular "release" in a future so, as far as I can get with my git knowledge what I do in order to accomplish this is to create a branch (for example: release/appname_vxx.xx.xxx_bbddvxx)

In remote:

```
"Master" > "Create branch from here" > release/appname_vxx.xx.xxx_bbddvxx
```

In local:

```
git fetch
git checkout -b release/appname_vxx.xx.xxx_bbddvxx
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/release/appname_vxx.xx.xxx_bbddvxx
git switch master > return to master and keep working on it.

Whenever bugfixes/modifications are needed:

git switch release/appname_vxx.xx.xxx_bbddvxx
git add . and git commit (after changes)
git switch
git switch master > return to master and keep working on it.
```

In short, what I do is to create a new branch on every new release with an identifying app and database version name to save the state for possible future use.

I'd like to know if my approach for saving (and keeping) development state (when new releases are launched) is correct/the most common way to accomplish this and if not, what would be a better way to go.

Comment: It’s really hard to say if what you are doing is what you need, because you did not really describe your needs or what downsides your current workflow has for you.

Comment: Actually you are doing good things. Branches are very lightweight in git, so you can have multiple branches without any issues. Just don't forget to push your branches to remote server if you want to have synchronized repos

Comment: Hello @kirelagin, my question is quite clear, I need to save current development state whenever I launch a new release of my app in case I need to make any changes/bugfixes in a future on that particular version. I don't know why I was downvoted for asking this though, as I'm not exactly asking for advice, it's the first time I do this and I've pasted some code I would use and I just need to know if this is the correct way to go.

Comment: Hello @Saboteur, thank you very much for your reply. Short and very helpful! Do you see something incorrect in my answer for being downvoted?

Comment: Every commit in git is a snapshot of the entire project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the usual thing is to make a *tag*.

A tag is exactly like a branch except that it doesn’t move. A branch moves as new commits are added, but a tag stays with one commit forever, marking and naming it and making it trivial to find. And it preserves its commit forever, because in git, names are what preserves things. Thus a tag is exactly the kind of “saving” you are looking for.

All my released apps are full of tags marking the versions and stages of release on TestFlight and the App Store, but I have only one branch, master, because I work solo. If there’s a crash or problem with a released version, I just checkout the corresponding tag.

Comment: Hello  @matt, thank you very much for your helpful and detailed response. I'll search about git tag, but would you mind editing your answer and adding a basic example of how you use it? BTW, I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Hi @DiegoPerez, the docs are here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging Note that you usually want an "annotated" tag, but it makes no difference in general, a tag is a permanent name for a commit and that's what you need. As you can see from the book, the classic example _is_ your situation, i.e. released versions.